# want to implement tabbbar screens shown in a single column and when the user scrolls the active tabbar changes accordingly

Tags: flutter, cross-platform

lets say I have 4 tabbar screens.i easily implements the screens to be showed when a user clicks on different tabs.

What I want to achieve right now is, I want to show all these 4 tab screens in a single column and when user scroll up, the active tabbar will update accordingly. also when a user clicks on any tabbar, the screen will animate to that portion of the screen (please provide the code so that I can understand more easily).

Comment: Looks like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66414421/is-there-a-flutter-equivalent-to-bootstrap-scrollspy

Comment: it is only implementing the scroll up feature. what I also want is when a user click on the tab the screen should animate to the specific portion of screen.